# Remove Image Source in silverlight for WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to programatically remove the source of an Image file?  Or is it better to just set the source to a new bitmap that is undefined?

The current way I'm doing it is:

```
BitmapImage bmpClear = new BitmapImage();
                CanvasImg.Source = bmpClear;
```

I never set the source of bmpClear, so the previous image that was set to CanvasImg is removed with nothing to replace it.  Is this a good solution or will this cause unintended consequences?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to just set it to null and clear it out

```
CanvasImg.Source = null;
```

But your solution should work just fine as well.

Comment: I would use the CanvasImg.Source = null and not create an object that will need to be Garbage Collected. Microsoft has even said that before here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/10/28/silverlight-bugs-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: Thank you.  I knew there had to be an easy solution.  The way I was doing it just didn't seem right.